# Отправка формы с помощью Ajax+Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, ajax, controller, model

я хочу сделать отправка формы с ошибкой, но все равно отправляется. Вот код:

**View**, **Controllers**, **Models** и **JS**

````
View
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
         <form  method="post" action="send_message">
             <div id="msg" class="text-center lead">
              <div class="form-group anim1" style="display: none;" >
              <label for="email" class="lead">Email</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Алиса" value="sm@gmail.com">
            </div>
              <div class="form-group anim1 text-center">
              <label for="name" class="lead">Ваше имя</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Алиса" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group anim1">
              <label for="phone1" class="lead">Ваш телефон</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone1" name="phone1" placeholder="88005553535" required>
            </div>
            
            <button type="button" class="btn c4_button_konsult lead buy">Заявка на консультацию</button>
          </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>
</div> 

Controllers
public function send_message()
 {

    if (!empty($_POST))
        {
          $data['msg'] = '';
            $msg='<img src="img/success.png" style="width: 50px;"> Заявка отправлена. Успешно!';
            $email_sm = $this->users_model->email_sm();
         //   $this->load->library('email');
        
            $this->email->from($_POST['email']);
            $this->email->to($email_sm['email']);
          //  $this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
          //  $this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');
            
            $this->email->subject('Клиент SHULGINA MAKEUP');
            $this->email->message('Имя: '.$_POST['name'].', Телефон: '.$_POST['phone1']);
  // var_dump($_POST);
  // var_dump($admin_email['email']);
        
            $this->email->send();
            // $data['msg'] = 'Заявка отправлена. Успешно.';
            echo $msg;
 }

}

Models

public function email_sm() {
    $sql = "select email from account where level='Админ'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->row_array();
}

JS (для Ajax)
$(document).ready(function () { // после загрузки документа
$('.buy').click(function() { // по щелчку по кнопке класса ок
// в переменные заносим значения элементов с определенными ID
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var phone1 = document.getElementById("phone1").value;
// ajax запрос формируем 
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', // метод
    url: 'send_message', // URL - куда отправить (ссылка)
    //массив данных Имя: значение
    data:({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phone1: phone1}),
    dataType: 'html',
    //в случае успешного выполнения
    success: function(result) {
        // занести то, что вернул нам метод контроллера в элемент с id= msg
        $("#msg").html(result);
    }
});
});

})```
````

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в конце метода контроллера `exit()`;

```
public function send_message()
 {

    if (!empty($_POST))
        {
          $data['msg'] = '';
            $msg='<img src="img/success.png" style="width: 50px;"> Заявка отправлена. Успешно!';
            $email_sm = $this->users_model->email_sm();
         //   $this->load->library('email');
        
            $this->email->from($_POST['email']);
            $this->email->to($email_sm['email']);
          //  $this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
          //  $this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');
            
            $this->email->subject('Клиент SHULGINA MAKEUP');
            $this->email->message('Имя: '.$_POST['name'].', Телефон: '.$_POST['phone1']);
  // var_dump($_POST);
  // var_dump($admin_email['email']);
        
            $this->email->send();
            // $data['msg'] = 'Заявка отправлена. Успешно.';
            echo $msg;
            exit();
 }
```